# Losing the value of a variable javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Why am I losing the value of a variable `one`?
I tried to declare the variable as a global variable and it didn't work.
I also tried some console.log commands, but didn't understand what happened.

```
function check() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
}
let one; // 1
function ready() {
  let button = document.getElementById("transform");
  let div = document.getElementById("objectImg");
  let img = document.getElementById("dog");

  console.log(div);
  console.log(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", function(a) {
    if (img) {
      img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
      div.innerHTML = "<img id = 'red' src = 'img/cat.jpg'>";
      one = document.getElementById("red");
      img = false;
      console.log(one); // <img id="red" src="img/cat.jpg">
    } else {

      alert("some text");
    }
  });
  console.log(one); // undefined
  //  one.addEventListener("mouseover", (a) => {
  //     });
}
check();
```

Comment: `one` is set only when the event listener is executed. Not after it's *attached*. After `.addEventLister("click", func)` you still need to wait for the actual click.

Comment: u have assigned value for variable `one` inside of a click event which is getting assigned when user clicks but your console log printing it on page load so its empty at the time of page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are calling the `one` before it's initiated, so as per the below code you can call the function once the `one` variable is assigned with some values, then you will get value.

```js
let one;

(function () {
  
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(a) {
  
    one = 56
  
    console.log('one from button click event: ' + one)
    
    callWhenOneIsSet()
    
  })
  
})()

function callWhenOneIsSet() {
  console.log('one from callWhenOneIsSet: ' + one)
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are setting the value to `one` inside an event listener. The code inside the event listener is executed ***after*** the button is clicked.
So, set the value to `one` outside of the event listener